# Map Autodesk Forge heatmaps to room - Data Visualization Api

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

Okay so I've been trying to map some heatmaps to a Revit room using the DataViz api. I was able to get X Y Z from Revit for the sensor inside the rooms, i've substracted the `viewer.model.getGlobalOffset()` and managed to show some sprites on these points. I know for a fact that those sprites / points are inside Rooms, but whenever I try to use the same points to load a heatmap I get the `Some devices did not map to a room:` warning and no heatmap is displayed.

Following the API documentation this warning appears when there is no room information in the point. Did I miss anything? This is "my" code:

```
async function loadHeatmaps(model){
  
  const dataVizExtn = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DataVisualization"); 
  // Given a model loaded from Forge
const structureInfo = new Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.ModelStructureInfo(model);

const devices = [
    {
        id: "Oficina 6", // An ID to identify this device
        name:"Oficina-",
        position: { x: 22.475382737884104, y: 7.4884431474006163, z: 3.0 }, // World coordinates of this device
        sensorTypes: ["temperature", "humidity"], // The types/properties this device exposes
    }
];
var offset = viewer.model.getGlobalOffset();
removeOffset(devices[0],offset)
// Generates `SurfaceShadingData` after assigning each device to a room.
const shadingData =  await structureInfo.generateSurfaceShadingData(devices);
  console.log(shadingData)
// Use the resulting shading data to generate heatmap from.
await dataVizExtn.setupSurfaceShading(model, shadingData);

// Register color stops for the heatmap. Along with the normalized sensor value
// in the range of [0.0, 1.0], `renderSurfaceShading` will interpolate the final
// heatmap color based on these specified colors.
const sensorColors = [0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0xffff00, 0xff0000];

// Set heatmap colors for temperature
const sensorType = "temperature";
dataVizExtn.registerSurfaceShadingColors(sensorType, sensorColors);
// Function that provides sensor value in the range of [0.0, 1.0]
function getSensorValue(surfaceShadingPoint, sensorType) {
  // The `SurfaceShadingPoint.id` property matches one of the identifiers passed
  // to `generateSurfaceShadingData` function. In our case above, this will either
  // be "cafeteria-entrace-01" or "cafeteria-exit-01".
  const deviceId = surfaceShadingPoint.id;

  // Read the sensor data, along with its possible value range
  let sensorValue = readSensorValue(deviceId, sensorType);
  const maxSensorValue = getMaxSensorValue(sensorType);
  const minSensorValue = getMinSensorValue(sensorType);

  // Normalize sensor value to [0, 1.0]
  sensorValue = (sensorValue - minSensorValue) / (maxSensorValue - minSensorValue);
  return clamp(sensorValue, 0.0, 1.0);
}

// This value can also be a room instead of a floor
const floorName = "01 - Entry Level";
dataVizExtn.renderSurfaceShading(floorName, sensorType, getSensorValue);


} 

function removeOffset(pos, offset) {
  pos.position.x = pos.position.x - offset.x;
  pos.position.y = pos.position.y - offset.y;
  pos.position.z = pos.position.z - offset.z;
}
```

And I'm calling the `loadHeatmaps()` function inside `onDocumentLoadSuccess` callback.

[image: Sprites and rooms but no heatmaps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: It looks like in this particular case it was a problem with `floorName` not being set to the right value. Note that this value (first parameter to `dataVizExtn.renderSurfaceShading`) should be set either to the name of the room, or to the name of the floor you want to update.

The offsets are a bit tricky so I'd suggest debugging that area, for example:

- What coordinate system are the sensors defined in? If they are in the same coordinate system as the building model itself, you shouldn't subtract or add any offset to them. Whenever there's a model with a "global offset" in its metadata, it basically means that the Model Derivative service moved the model to origin to avoid floating point precision issues, and the viewer will then add the global offset back to each geometry when its loaded.
- Try using the viewer APIs to get the bounding box of one of the rooms that the devices should map to, and see if the bounding box actually contains the XYZ point of the device you're trying to pass into the DataViz extension. The bounds of any object can be found like so:

```js
function getObjectBounds(model, dbid) {
    const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
    const frags = model.getFragmentList();
    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragid) {
        let _bounds = new THREE.Box3();
        frags.getWorldBounds(fragid, _bounds);
        bounds.union(_bounds);
    }, true);
    return bounds;
}
```

Comment: Sensors are not included yet in the model so I got the coordinates from revit by hand until they are placed. I've used the getObjectBounds function you suggested and hardcoded the coordinates right in the middle of the room, yet I'm getting the same warning and no heatmap.  I've noticed that room information is hidden by default. Could that make any difference? Thank you for your time Petr.

Comment: I've also console.logged the info from structureInfo.generateSurfaceShadingData(devices) for you if that gives you any kind of help: [Image](https://imgur.com/CggVkcL)

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. The rooms can definitely stay hidden, that shouldn't make any difference. One more idea: is your Revit design perhaps using a language other than English?

Comment: Nope, even tho the model was created in Spanish, I've changed the language to english by opening it in Revit English and saving it in english, and I know that if I try to find any properties or category names i have to do it in English. As you can see in the question's image, the word "Rooms" is displayed in english.

Comment: I have new information!! I've made a viewer.getProperties() of the room dbid and these are the properties of the room : [Image](https://imgur.com/rGr47Mk)  The room lost all properties and IDK why or when. This is the problem right?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. How exactly did you retrieve the room dbID?

Comment: I've selected it and did viewer.getSelection() via the chrome console for testing porpouses

Comment: I've made some more tests and if I do viewer.model.getBulkProperties() of the same DBID and with some properties that I know that exists I actually get the props. [Image](https://imgur.com/E9FdkDU)

Comment: Ok, that seems to be correct. In that case I think I'm gonna have to ask you to share the Revit model with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` (we will not share it with anyone outside of Autodesk), so that we can debug the issue on our end. And please include a reference to this Stack Overflow question in the email, too.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and my revit model was built by revit 2020. When I update model to 2022, heatmap can show on the room correctly.